# Upgrading PostGIS 3.0 to PostGIS 3.3 on RHEL 8 fails

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-raster, upgrade

I am not a DBA.

I am trying to update our PostGIS 3.0 package installation on a PostgreSQL 12 database to PostGIS 3.3 package on a RHEL 8 server. I am unable to install both packages at the same time and migrate the database extensions to the newer version due to some conflicts.

Example -

```
dnf install postgis33

file /usr/pgsql-12/lib/address_standardizer-3.so from install of postgis33_12-3.3.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis30_12-3.0.7-1.rhel8.x86_64

file /usr/pgsql-12/lib/postgis-3.so from install of postgis33_12-3.3.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis30_12-3.0.7-1.rhel8.x86_64

file /usr/pgsql-12/lib/postgis_raster-3.so from install of postgis33_12-3.3.5-1PGDG.rhel8.x86_64 conflicts with file from package postgis30_12-3.0.7-1.rhel8.x86_64

If I uninstall PostGIS 3.0 package and try to install PostGIS 3.3 package there are a lot of dependencies that would be removed but this seems to not be an option or it could break our current PostGIS installation. 

Example - 

dnf uninstall postgis30

Removing unused dependencies:

 CGAL                                    x86_64                 4.14-1.rhel8                                      @reposync-pgdg12-common                                   2.0 M

 CharLS                                  x86_64                 2.0.0-6.el8                                       @epel                                                     347 k


 OpenEXR-libs                            x86_64                 2.2.0-12.el8                                      @rhel-8-server-AppStream                                  3.1 M

 SFCGAL                                  x86_64                 1.4.1-13.rhel8                                    @reposync-pgdg12-common                                    32 k

 SFCGAL-libs                             x86_64                 1.4.1-13.rhel8                                    @reposync-pgdg12-common                                    11 M
```

How do I get PostGIS 3.3 package installed on RHEL 8 using PostgreSQL 12 from the official PostgreSQL repository so I can update the database extensions?

Comment: PowerTools? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377993/749066

Comment: PostgreSQL 12 is ancient stuff (end-of-life in Nov). You really ought to be installing modern PostGIS in a modern PostgreSQL. It will be way easier to find compatibility with a modern database.

Comment: Oh, and RHEL8 is near-death as well (May 31), so you really ought to start with a modern OS.

Comment: I double-checked and it looks like I have the CodeReady repo active. 

Postgres 12 is all I have at the moment and unfortunately, it is not an option to upgrade. I do see that its EOL is in November. I will have to bring that up to management.

RHEL 8.10 will eventually come out and expand support to 2029. Is there something else I can try within those constraints that I have?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing PostGIS 3.0 and allowed the dependencies to be removed. Then I installed PostGIS 3.3 and the new dependencies were installed with it. There are some other dependency issues but that is out of scope for this article.